What is reportgenerator@5 Couldn't find it in Azure Documentation
I am currently investigating a block of code.
objective is to generate a report and place it in a target directory.
I looked up for documentation for what is reportgenerator@5 but could find it in the Azure documentation.
For reference:
- task: reportgenerator@5   
  displayName: Generates Coverage Reports in CoverageResultsFolder   
  inputs:
    reports: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/**/*.cobertura.xml'
    targetdir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/CoverageResults'

I am trying to find out what reportgenerator@5 is and any documentation to help with the understanding of its implementation, but I cannot find it anywhere online.

The reportgenerator@5 task is not the buildt-in task in Azure DevOps. So you are not able to find it in the Azure Documentation.
This is an extension task from the Extension: ReportGenerator

ReportGenerator converts coverage reports generated by coverlet, OpenCover, dotCover, Visual Studio, NCover, Cobertura, JaCoCo, Clover, gcov, or lcov into human readable reports in various formats.

You need to install the extension in your Organization, then you can use the reportgenerator@5 task in the Azure Pipeline.
For more detailed info, you can refer to the doc: ReportGenerator and Usage Guide
